# Java Apache Poi SXSSF with Excel Macros

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a excel template that has macros (.xlsm), I want to read it in, add a million rows to it and write it out.

I know that reading and re-writing files with POI that contain macros will preserve the macros. I need to write out the excel using SXSSF (ram limitations), but SXSSF doesn't read files.

Question: How can I read in an excel with macros using XSSF, and then write out the excel with macros using SXSSF?

Comment: Please take a few minutes and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI supports writing a spreadsheet with a large number of rows via SXSSFWorkbook based on a "template workbook". See the [relevant constructor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook)) for details.

So you would open the .xlsm via `XSSFWorkbook` and then create the `SXSSFWorkbook` with that as template.

This should also keep the macros in place as far as I see.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you need to have a certain amount of "reputation-points" before you can accept answers..