# Protect a SXSSFWorkbook (Excel) and convert it to a byte array

Tags: java, excel, encryption, bytearrayoutputstream, sxssf

I am working on a Java function which is expected to return a protected Excel file (xlsx) in byte array.

```
public byte[] genProtectedExcel() {
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //Code of cells fill in...

    //Should be code of workbook encryption...

    workbook.write(baos);
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

I found a solution which used the Encryption support of Apache POI: [How to Protect Excel Workbook Via SXSSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898448/how-to-protect-excel-workbook-via-sxssf)

```
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);

Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
enc.confirmPassword("foobaa");

InputStream is = <open the SXSSF workbook as stream>
OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
IOUtils.copy(is, os);
```

However, OutputStream cannot be cast into ByteArrayOutputStream. I tried to find a way to convert the OutputStream into ByteArray but all failed.
Is there anyway to create a protect excel byte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

fs.writeFilesystem(baos );

return baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: In fact, the inputstream and outputstream represent the direction of data. Data is transferred from one place to another, which can be memory, hard disk, or network I/O.The input and output streams cannot be directly converted."OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);" creates an outputstream that points to the POIFSFileSystem.After the "IOUtils.copy(is, os);" is executed, the data is stored in the memory of the POIFSFileSystem.